# Different output while using fit_transform vs fit and transform from sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

The following code snippet illustrates the issue:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

(nrows, ncolumns) = (1912392, 131)

X = np.random.random((nrows, ncolumns))

pca = PCA(n_components=28, random_state=0)
transformed_X1 = pca.fit_transform(X)
pca1 = pca.fit(X)
transformed_X2 = pca1.transform(X)

print((transformed_X1 != transformed_X2).sum()) # Gives output as 53546976


scalar = StandardScaler()
scaled_X1 = scalar.fit_transform(X)
scalar2 = scalar.fit(X)
scaled_X2 = scalar2.transform(X)

(scaled_X1 != scaled_X2).sum() # Gives output as 0
```

Can someone explain as to why the first output is not zero and the second output is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this works:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=28, svd_solver = 'full')
transformed_X1 = pca.fit_transform(X)
pca1 = pca.fit(X)
transformed_X2 = pca1.transform(X)

print(np.allclose(transformed_X1, transformed_X2))
True
```

Apparently `svd_solver = 'random'` (which is what `'auto'` defaults to) has enough process difference between `.fit(X).transform(X)` and `fit_transform(X)` to give different results even with the same seed.  Also remember floating point errors make `==` and `/=` unreliable judges of equality of different processes, so use `np.allclose()`.

It seems like `StandardScaler.fit_transform()` just directly uses `.fit(X).transform(X)` under the hood, so there were no floating point errors there to trip you up.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the issue!